# new Keyword is used for creating object without assigning to an object reference

Tags: java, multithreading, new-operator

Currently i am referring Thread class in  java .so i came across a program  in which  object is created  without referring to  to the object reference.can anyone explain the concept

here is the code

```
// Create a second thread.
class NewThread implements Runnable {
Thread t;
NewThread() {
// Create a new, second thread
t = new Thread(this, "Demo Thread");
System.out.println("Child thread: " + t);
t.start(); // Start the thread
}
// This is the entry point for the second thread.
public void run() {
try {
for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
System.out.println("Child Thread: " + i);
Thread.sleep(500);
}
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
System.out.println("Child interrupted.");
}
System.out.println("Exiting child thread.");
}
}
```

Main Program

```
class ThreadDemo {
public static void main(String args[]) {
new NewThread(); // create a new thread
try {
for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
System.out.println("Main Thread: " + i);
Thread.sleep(1000);
}
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
System.out.println("Main thread interrupted.");
}
System.out.println("Main thread exiting.");
}
}
```

here new is used for creating thread without reference to any  object reference.shouldn't be the code like

NewThread ob =new NewThread(); instead of just new NewThread(); in the main method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "new NewThread()" creates a new object, calling its constructor.  The constructor starts a thread.  Simple enough.  The new Thread object remains "live" (i.e., it will not be garbage collected) as long as it continues to run because there is a reference to the Thread object from the thread's stack.

The code contains the seed of a bug though.  The NewThread constructor leaks "this".  That is to say, it passes its "this" reference to another object (the new Thread object) which means that methods of the new Thread object potentially can see the NewThread before the NewThread has been completely initialized.  That's probably a benign error in this case because the NewThread object doesn't appear to have any state, but in a more complicated program, leaking "this" from a constructor can have serious consequences.

Comment: oh thanks james  i have been referring herbert schildt's java book for studying & the code is from his book.This is the first time i was seeing new keyword using this way.That's y i asked the question.by the way how did you find a bug from standard book,i am finding it difficult to understand the concepts itself.u must be having high experience in java to see through these kind of bugs,do u think a noob like me can become more like you??

Comment: Lots of books have mistakes (google for "erratum").  In this case, it's more of a bad example than an actual bug.  There were several reasons why I don't like that example, and now I have a new one which is, that you had a hard time understanding it.  Once you've got your basic programming skills, I suggest you read a book called _Clean Code_ by Robert C. Martin.  It's a manifesto that calls for _all_ code to be so simple, and so obvious that even the rankest noob can read it and understand what's going on.  (And yeah, I was a noob once.  Just don't get impatient and give up.)

Comment: Concepts which i said difficult to understand was from the book not which  is explained above . do u mind answering one more question .it is about  basic programming skills  said in the answer. can u tell me how to acquire those skills maybe  u can mention the topics which i have to cover,any techniques,books which are simple to understand or any sites.hope this won't bother u.

Comment: @sweet_revathy569, I'm sorry, I don't know.  The first things I learned--basic skills--were from so long ago that they are barely relevant today.  Everything else, I learned on the job.  I don't keep up with who's teaching beginners or what or how they are teaching them.  It's enough of a challenge just to keep up with what *I* need to know to survive in an industry that is still evolving.  All I can say is, keep at it, and good luck.